# Reuse core data created .db file in FMDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, core-data, fmdb

I'm using Core Data to manage local DB in my iOS app.  But then I have a requirement to  insert bulk of records to local DB. So I choose [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to perform bulk insertion. But when I tried to insert the record I'm getting this **DB Error: 1 "no such table: Table Name**.
But when I cross checked,  the local DB exist there with all the tables that I created in xcdatamodel.

```
- (FMDatabase *)dbInMainThread{

    if (_dbInMainThread) {
         return _dbInMainThread;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[[CoreDataManager manager] applicationLibraryDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[DATABASE_NAME stringByAppendingString:@".sqlite"]];
    [self checkDB:[storeURL relativePath]];

    _dbInMainThread = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[storeURL relativePath]];
    return _dbInMainThread;
}

-(void) checkDB:(NSString *)dbpath{

    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fm fileExistsAtPath:dbpath];

    if (success) return;


    }
```

Success `bool` in the above code snippet is always returning `true`.

I followed the steps in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177165/fmdb-ios-no-such-table) answer.
Since I am using Core Data, I don't need to add the DB file to the project. I uninstalled the app, resets the simulator and verified the DB file was in the correct folder before starting insertion. But nothing helps.

What am I missing here

Thanks

Comment: there may be a connection problem between app and DB ..have you properly installed fmdb cocoapods ..

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible for FMDB to access DB file created by Core Data ?

Comment: @vaibhav Yes I installed the FMDB without any issue. Can you specify what exactly is the connection issue ?. It worked well with Core Data before.

Comment: if it is reused by sqlite so it can be in fmdb have a look of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901694/does-core-data-create-a-sqlite-database-file-automatically) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348206/creating-sqlite-file-from-core-data-store) may gives any solution for ..

Comment: if the table exists inside db and worked well with core data so probably its a connection prob in which unable to find table.. change your ques header may gets attn